# A number of philosophers believes

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

'A number of philosophers believe' sounds right to me. Not only because philosophers is plural, but also number, while singular, has a plural meaning.

Also having the s - s ending in 'philosophers believes' is awkward because philosophers are plural and are the ones doing the believing.

'A number of philosophers believes' seems pedantically grammatically correct, since it is **a** number, so number is singular. But it sounds wrong to my ear.

What's the "right" way?

Comment: The question is, "If you were to substitute a pronoun for "A number of philosophers" would it be **"it"** or **"they"**?" If it is **it**, then this implies that the number is doing the believing... this is not possible - numbers can't believe anything.  More simply, "a number [of nouns]" = an indefinite quantity of nouns that is more than one.

Comment: "A number" is what's known as a 'number transparent noun phrase'. The fact that it is singular doesn't affect the agreement of the verb.

Comment: Compare 'A couple/score of philosophers believe ....'